# Symfony Form div css class

Tags: forms, symfony, customization

Using Symfony 3 and building a form field like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('tittle')
    ->add('price');
```

The result is something like:

```
<div>
    <label ...></label>
    <input ...>
</div>
```

and I want the result to include custom css classes in the wrapping `div`, like:

```
<div class='wrap-title'>
    <label ...></label>
    <input ...>
</div>
<div class='wrap-price'>
    <label ...></label>
    <input ...>
</div>
```

Trying to do as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes) doesn't offer a way to add a class to the wrapping `div`, just the things inside it.

I don't want to use the bootstrap themes. I really need to add something of my own as a class there. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this answer can helps you:

I do not think it's possible to create div element inside the formbuilder.

If you can use Twig then you can render each of the three parts of the field individually inside a div having your custom class

```
<div class=wrap-title"">
    {{ form_label(form.title) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.title) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.title) }}
</div>
<div class=wrap-price"">
    {{ form_label(form.price) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.price) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.price) }}
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I was just reading about that [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/rendering.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand). I'll use this approach. Thanks.

Comment: The solution from Mintho433 is nice for one form but if you look for a application-wide solution you should use form themes. Please take a few minutes to read this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#method-2-inside-a-separate-template